# How i can copy the same transaction of 1 address on ethereum?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, wallets, etherscan, addresses

How i can copy the same transaction of 1 address on ethereum ?I mean like a copytrading onchain... I choose 1 address and my addres do the same thing automatically.

Comment: The address that i want to copy is a contract.

Comment: Contracts do not generate transactions. You cannot copy them. You could copy the transaction that calls the contract.